# What does it mean by member initialization list initializing an attribute of a class

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, member-initialization

If I have a class like the below one:

```
class foo {
  private:
    int a;
  public:
    foo (int arg1) : a(arg1) {}
};
```

The attribute `a` will be default-initialized in the line it got declared.
Now, when the parameterized constructor is called, it gets re-initialized to the value `arg1` in the member-initialization list.

1. Is my understanding correct that `a` gets re-initialized in the member initialization list?
2. If yes, what does it mean by an attribute getting re-initialized (Initialization means memory getting allocated. Now, what does re-initialization mean?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `a` won't be "re-initialized", i.e. initialized twice. When the parameterized constructor is used `a` will *only* be [direct-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) from the constructor parameter `arg1`, no default-initialization happens.

If `foo` has another constructor which doesn't initialize `a` in member-init-list, then it'll be [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). E.g.

```
class foo {
  private:
    int a;
  public:
    foo (int arg1) : a(arg1) {} // a is direct-initialized from arg1 when this constructor used
    foo () {}                   // a is default-initialized when this constructor used
};
```

Comment: My understanding is that `foo () {}` leaves `a` uninitialized. https://godbolt.org/z/KT68nEq9G

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, that's the effect of [default initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) an `int`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Just wanting to point it out since many seem to assume that default initialization means `a` would be initialized to 0.

Comment: @songyuanyao so there won't be any kind of initialization in the 3rd line (`int a;`)?

Comment: @PhiloRobotist As a data member how it's initialized depends on how the whole class object is initialized (how constructor is called).

Comment: @PhiloRobotist We don't know how it'll be initialized from just `int a;`.